# Can't solve error PHPmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

When i register and account with my loginform and its supposed to send a confirmation email it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\mailer\class.phpmailer.php:1479
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\login\mailer\class.phpmailer.php(1562): PHPMailer->getSMTPInstance()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\login\mailer\class.phpmailer.php(1499): PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\login\mailer\class.phpmailer.php(1336): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Fri, 3 Ma...', 'This is a multi...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\login\mailer\class.phpmailer.php(1214): PHPMailer->postSend()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\login\class.user.php(106): PHPMailer->send()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\login\signup.php(43): USER->send_mail('Rainier.laan@ho...', 'Hello Rainier, ...', 'Confirm Registr...')
#6 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\mailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1479
```

I looked up what was on line 1479 and it was this:

```
if (!is_object($this->smtp)) {
        $this->smtp = new SMTP;
    }
```

I cant see what the error is. Im new to this. Can you guys help me?

Comment: you really need to show the coding..otherwise....no way to help you

Comment: You are probably not including the autoloader. See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/113

Comment: That github issue was painful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

**Using PHPMailer's own autoloader**

Not so long ago, PHPMailer changed the way that it loaded classes so that it was more compatible with composer, many frameworks, and the PHP PSR-0 autoloading standard. Note that because we support PHP back to version 5.0, we cannot support the more recent PSR-4 standard, nor can we use namespaces. Previously, PHPMailer loaded the SMTP class explicitly, and this causes problems if you want to provide your own implementation. You may have seen old scripts doing this:

```
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
```

If you do only that, SMTP sending will fail with a ***Class 'SMTP' not found error***. You need to either explicitly include the class.smtp.php file (read the README for info on which files you need), or use the recommended approaches of using composer or the supplied autoloader, like this:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have download all the project files. The SMTP class code is defined into the PHPMailer project, in [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php) file .

If you downloaded PHPMailer with composer, ensure you have a line like `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php`. Otherwise, check if you have a line like `require_once 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php` before to use the PHPMailer classes.

Comment: "Otherwise, check if you have a line like require_once 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php before to use the PHPMailer classes." > it's obviously not the inclusion of the phpmailer class itself that is the problem, the error occurs on instantiating the SMTP class. He should simply include composer's or phpmailer's autloader.

Comment: This is what I mean by saying  "check if you have a line like require_once 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php before to use the PHPMailer classes"

Comment: No problems ! Your 1st comment was clear enough for @eudelcosine148